# Auto complete textbox which display name but store id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

> header.php file for send caegory id and return sub category name

```
 <?php 
     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "iraa");
 ?>
 Category :
<select  id="category_id" name="cat_id" required=""  class="form-control" tabindex="2" onselect ="getSubcat()">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT category_id,category_name FROM categories_master";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                              
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $data['category_id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['category_name'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

Sub Category : 
<select id="sub_cat_id" required  name="sub_cat_id"  class="form-control " tabindex="2">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>

<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="//rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#category_id').editableSelect();
    function getSubcat() {
        var category_id=$("#category_id").val();
        alert(category_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_subcategory.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {category_id: category_id},
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $('#sub_cat_id').html(response);
        });
    }
</script>
```

> get_subcategory.php file for get ajax response and return sub category

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "iraa");
$sql = "SELECT sub_category_id,sub_category_name FROM sub_categories_master WHERE category_id='$_POST[category_id]'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                              
?>
<option value="<?php echo $data['sub_category_id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['sub_category_name'] ?></option>
```

> This return category name but i want category id not category name
>   [image]

Comment: Dude have you checked the answer?

Comment: I checked answer, but it's not work. because i used editableSelect() method there for when script is execute at that time its convert <select> tag into textbox. So, I can't get value. Please Check in DOM and style Inspector.

Comment: OK dude, I have updated my answer below.

Comment: Thank You very much sir. It's Work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the jQuery editableSelect plugin, you may want to look at the [Listen changes](http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/).

Example:

```
Category :
<select  id="category_id" name="cat_id" required="" class="form-control" tabindex="2">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
<pre>Last selected: <span id="last-selected"></span></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#category_id')
    .editableSelect()
    .on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
        $('#last-selected').html(
            li.val() + '. ' + li.text()
        );
    });
</script>
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/dpaf13n7/7/

So the data I guess you are looking for is `li.val()`.

If you edit the select option, then there won't be a value.

I hope this helps you out.